# If a person is tried for fraud for practicing law without a degree, and the verdict is not guilty, would double jeopardy prevent future fraud charges?

Tags: fraud, double-jeopardy, law-in-fiction

[SPOILERS for *Suits*]

In season five of the TV series *Suits*, Mike Ross, who has practised law for a few years without a degree and passing the Bar himself, is tried for fraud. The jury's verdict is revealed to be not guilty.

Does this mean that Mike could continue to practise law without a licence and never face fraud charges again, or could a new fact pattern emerge if he continued to practise without a licence post-acquittal, opening himself up to prosecution again?

Comment: There's a movie, "Double Jeopardy", that gets this dead wrong. The summary from IMDB: "A woman framed for her husband's murder suspects he is still alive; as she has already been tried for the crime, she can't be re-prosecuted if she finds and kills him." She can be prosecuted, because killing him after the trial is a different crime than the one she was charged with.

Comment: @PJB: That seems like a very... ill-conceived plan on her part.

Comment: @V2Blast -- it was also an ill-conceived movie. <g>

Comment: So does the character in question not have the law degree or the law license.  These are two very different documents.  Can you link to a synopsis of the episode(s) this occurred in?

Comment: @hszmv He had neither a law degree nor law licence. I couldn't get a synopsis exactly, but here's an episode recap: https://www.google.com/amp/s/hungrynovelist.wordpress.com/2016/03/08/suits-recap-season-5-episode-16-25th-hour/amp/

Comment: The person certainly could try and pass the Bar, though the past unlicensed practice of law might be a morals issue.

Comment: Practicing law without a degree might be illegal, but not as fraud. As in medicine, the fraud would be falsely claiming to have a degree… 

The Question seems to depend on what "future fraud charges" might mean.

If the suggestion is that being cleared of one fraud charge provides a "Get out of Jail Free" card for fending off future fraud charges then no; why would you think that?

Why would fraud be different from theft or murder, for instance? Get off once, gain free plays forever?

No… Go back to Start. Do not pass Go. Do not collect (anything)

Answer (score 18):

### No

The charge would more likely be "Unlicensed practice of law" (UPL), possibly in addition to a charge of fraud. Each time that Rose engages in UPL would be a separate offense, and could lead to a fresh trial.

This is no more covered by double jeopardy than a serial killer gets a free pass on future killings because s/he was acquitted of one particular murder.

The exact definition of UPL varies by state, but making a living as a lawyer without a license is UPL in every US state, I think.

For a work of fiction in which UPL is central, see *The Rooster Bar* by John Grisham.

Comment: Pretty much answers my question. I thought this was the case. Thank you.

Comment: "living as a lawyer without a license is UPL in every US state, I think." No need to "I think" about it, although there is some leniency given to jailhouse lawyers who are incarcerated and help fellow inmates without charge.

Comment: I did say "make a living": whoich rather implies chrgign fees on a regular basis.